# How can I get Spring's WebFlux to emit a response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I create a Spring-webflux webclient I'm not able to get it to go into the subscribe or doOnNext callback. I keep getting this error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The underlying HTTP client completed without emitting a response.

I've tried changing the baseurl during the creation of the webcilent. Tried a different uri after creating the webclient.

```
WebClient build = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("https://www.google.com").build();
Mono<String> t = build.get().uri("/{hi}", "hi").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).doOnNext(r->{
    System.out.println("aoeuaotnseuhte");
});

build.get().uri("https://www.google.com").exchange().subscribe(r->{
    System.out.println("aotnsehu this was not a triumph");
});


client.get().uri("/{test}", "test").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).subscribe(resp->{
    System.out.println("hai");   
});

client.get().uri("https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).subscribe(resp ->{
    System.out.println("hi");
});
```

I'm expecting a breakpoint to stop at any of those println statements, I've never been able to get a breakpoint to stop there.

environment details:
java 1.8.0_144
spring boot 2.1.5

console output

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:55458,suspend=y,server=n -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:C:\Users\Sam\.IdeaIC2019.1\system\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Sam\IdeaProjects\wondrous-magic\target\test-classes;C:\Users\Sam\IdeaProjects\wondrous-magic\target\classes;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-webflux\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-webflux-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.1.7.RELEASE\spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.1.7.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.1.7.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.11.2\log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.11.2\log4j-api-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.26\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.26.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.23\snakeyaml-1.23.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-json-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.8\jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.8\jackson-core-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.8\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.8\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.8\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\io\projectreactor\netty\reactor-netty\0.8.8.RELEASE\reactor-netty-0.8.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec-http\4.1.36.Final\netty-codec-http-4.1.36.Final.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-common\4.1.36.Final\netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-buffer\4.1.36.Final\netty-buffer-4.1.36.Final.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport\4.1.36.Final\netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-resolver\4.1.36.Final\netty-resolver-4.1.36.Final.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec\4.1.36.Final\netty-codec-4.1.36.Final.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec-http2\4.1.36.Final\netty-codec-http2-4.1.36.Final.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-handler\4.1.36.Final\netty-handler-4.1.36.Final.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-handler-proxy\4.1.36.Final\netty-handler-proxy-4.1.36.Final.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec-socks\4.1.36.Final\netty-codec-socks-4.1.36.Final.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-native-epoll\4.1.36.Final\netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.36.Final-linux-x86_64.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-native-unix-common\4.1.36.Final\netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.36.Final.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\javax.el\3.0.0\javax.el-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.16.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.16.Final.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.4.0\classmate-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.1.7.RELEASE\spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.1.7.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webflux\5.1.7.RELEASE\spring-webflux-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\io\projectreactor\reactor-core\3.2.9.RELEASE\reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\reactivestreams\reactive-streams\1.0.2\reactive-streams-1.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\synchronoss\cloud\nio-multipart-parser\1.1.0\nio-multipart-parser-1.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\synchronoss\cloud\nio-stream-storage\1.1.3\nio-stream-storage-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-test\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-test-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-test\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-test-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-test-autoconfigure\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\assertj\assertj-core\3.11.1\assertj-core-3.11.1.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-core\2.23.4\mockito-core-2.23.4.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.9.12\byte-buddy-1.9.12.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy-agent\1.9.12\byte-buddy-agent-1.9.12.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\2.6\objenesis-2.6.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-library\1.3\hamcrest-library-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\skyscreamer\jsonassert\1.5.0\jsonassert-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\external\google\android-json\0.0.20131108.vaadin1\android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.1.7.RELEASE\spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.1.7.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\5.1.7.RELEASE\spring-test-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\xmlunit\xmlunit-core\2.6.2\xmlunit-core-2.6.2.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\com\jayway\jsonpath\json-path\2.4.0\json-path-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\net\minidev\json-smart\2.3\json-smart-2.3.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\net\minidev\accessors-smart\1.2\accessors-smart-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\5.0.4\asm-5.0.4.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.26\slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okhttp3\mockwebserver\3.14.1\mockwebserver-3.14.1.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okhttp3\okhttp\3.14.1\okhttp-3.14.1.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okio\okio\1.17.2\okio-1.17.2.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\org\jsoup\jsoup\1.11.3\jsoup-1.11.3.jar;C:\Users\Sam\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.6\commons-io-2.6.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 com.spry.magic.service.ApiServiceTest,test
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55458', transport: 'socket'
23:18:08.515 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
23:18:08.532 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - Platform: Windows
23:18:08.534 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
23:18:08.534 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - Java version: 8
23:18:08.535 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
23:18:08.536 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
23:18:08.536 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Buffer.address: available
23:18:08.536 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - direct buffer constructor: available
23:18:08.537 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Bits.unaligned: available, true
23:18:08.537 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(int): unavailable prior to Java9
23:18:08.537 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int): available
23:18:08.537 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - sun.misc.Unsafe: available
23:18:08.537 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.tmpdir: C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp (java.io.tmpdir)
23:18:08.537 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
23:18:08.539 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory: 7621050368 bytes
23:18:08.539 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.uninitializedArrayAllocationThreshold: -1
23:18:08.539 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.CleanerJava6 - java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner(): available
23:18:08.540 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
23:18:08.541 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack: false
23:18:08.541 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses: false
23:18:08.620 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - Loopback interface: lo (Software Loopback Interface 1, 127.0.0.1)
23:18:08.620 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - Failed to get SOMAXCONN from sysctl and file \proc\sys\net\core\somaxconn. Default: 200
23:18:08.623 [main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers$LoggerFactory - Using Slf4j logging framework
23:18:08.644 [main] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources - [http] resources will use the default LoopResources: DefaultLoopResources {prefix=reactor-http, daemon=true, selectCount=8, workerCount=8}
23:18:08.644 [main] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources - [http] resources will use the default ConnectionProvider: PooledConnectionProvider {name=http, poolFactory=reactor.netty.resources.ConnectionProvider$$Lambda$69/511832416@1acaf3d}
23:18:08.758 [main] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultLoopEpoll - Default Epoll support : false
23:18:08.758 [main] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultLoopKQueue - Default KQueue support : false
23:18:08.763 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup - -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 16
23:18:08.807 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.initialSize: 1024
23:18:08.807 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.maxSize: 4096
23:18:08.818 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false
23:18:08.818 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512
23:18:08.830 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - org.jctools-core.MpscChunkedArrayQueue: available
23:18:51.526 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions - [4de41af9] HTTP GET https://www.google.com
23:18:51.538 [main] DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl - netty-tcnative not in the classpath; OpenSslEngine will be unavailable.
23:18:51.784 [main] DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext - Default protocols (JDK): [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1] 
23:18:51.784 [main] DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext - Default cipher suites (JDK): [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
23:18:51.814 [main] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider - Creating new client pool [http] for www.google.com:443
23:18:51.825 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId - -Dio.netty.processId: 7664 (auto-detected)
23:18:51.908 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId - -Dio.netty.machineId: 30:5a:3a:ff:fe:02:74:f6 (auto-detected)
23:18:51.918 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level: simple
23:18:51.918 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.targetRecords: 4
23:18:51.968 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.numHeapArenas: 16
23:18:51.968 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas: 16
23:18:51.968 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.pageSize: 8192
23:18:51.969 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder: 11
23:18:51.969 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.chunkSize: 16777216
23:18:51.969 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.tinyCacheSize: 512
23:18:51.969 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.smallCacheSize: 256
23:18:51.969 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.normalCacheSize: 64
23:18:51.969 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedBufferCapacity: 32768
23:18:51.969 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimInterval: 8192
23:18:51.969 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimIntervalMillis: 0
23:18:51.969 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.useCacheForAllThreads: true
23:18:51.969 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedByteBuffersPerChunk: 1023
23:18:51.977 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.allocator.type: pooled
23:18:51.977 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 0
23:18:51.977 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.maxThreadLocalCharBufferSize: 16384
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55458', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

stack trace for java.lang.IllegalStateException: The underlying HTTP client completed without emitting a response.

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient.<clinit>(DefaultWebClient.java:70)
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClientBuilder.build(DefaultWebClientBuilder.java:212)
```

Edit: I was using the webclient incorrectly, the lambdas weren't getting executed because the program was exiting before a response was returned. Adding a block, like in chas spenlau's answer, fixed this for me.  chas spenlau's example worked for me, and the code examples above worked for me when I added the block.

Edit 2: I also needed to subscribe to the response. Using block subscribes and blocks, I could fix these statements by adding .subscribe to the end of each one. See Thomas's comment for a better explanation.

Comment: when you click to set your breakpoint it should ask if you want it to be on the line or on the lambda, is it asking you that? if so choose lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do, so sorry if this isn't helpful. But when you click to set your breakpoint it should ask if you want it to be on the line or on the lambda, is it asking you that? if so choose lambda.

[image]

I was able to place my breakpoint on that line in the following code and go inside the doOnNext

```
               webClient.get()
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .doOnNext(myString -> {System.out.println(myString);})
                .block();
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me figure out what exactly wasn't working with my code.

I'm very new to this type of handling http requests, and was expecting them to get a response before moving on. 

I was running all of these in a unit test, which would exit before it had a chance to get a response from the server. adding .block() made made it so all of the requests did go inside the lamda.

Comment: Block is not a good practice to use depending on what you want to do. Webclient is non blocking and when you call block you are making the request and then blocking all execution until the request has finished and then you display the result. That defeats the entire purpose of using WebClient.
You had no subscription to your stream of data thats why the call is never made and no data is flowing. Here you can read more about subscribing
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_simple_ways_to_create_a_flux_or_mono_and_subscribe_to_it

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense about the subscription. And explains why block works, and why it wasn't working without subscribe.

Comment: I could have been more informative about why what you had wasn't working, that's my fault. And to be clear I agree with Thomas, .block() should be almost never used except in very specific circumstances because it defeats the purpose. For general use case testing sure it works to illustrate points. Though in my initial writing of this answer I actually had code that was subscribing to that client call, I should have posted everything instead of just the small part I did. I added the .block() to make sure it would work stand-alone for you. My fault if my answer didn't provide good info.